# How can I ascertain which button called event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with two buttons: btn_oldFile and btn_newFile. Both buttons, on click call the function btnOnClick:

```
btn_oldFile.Click += btnOnClick;
btn_newFile.Click += btnOnClick;

protected void OldFileBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            //if btn_oldFile called
                // print to tbx_OldFile
            //else
                //print to tbx_NewFile
        }
```

For the most part, btnOnClick is to do the same thing no matter which button called itself, except for assigning a value to a variable. If btn_oldFile calls the method, I print some text to a textbox: tbx_OldFile, while if btn_newFile calls it, the text is printed to tbx_NewFile.

How can I ascertain which button was the one that called the method?

Comment: Perhaps there's a bigger context here that I'm missing, but If the two events are being handled differently, why are they being directed to the same handling method?

Comment: the two button click events are being handled the same except for one tiny difference. clicking the buttons brings up a file select box where you select a file. If you click on 'old file' button, I want the path of the file you selected t be save to a different varaiable than if you click on 'new file' and select a file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object that raised the event is passed to the event handler as the sender parameter, so you can cast that to the correct type to access it.

```
protected void OldFileBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
}
```

Edit: You can then use a basic if statement to check which button it was.

```
if (btn == btn_oldFile) // etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fara pointed out when a click occurs, the `Button` causing the click will be the first parameter.  However this solution requires a cast and can be foiled by a derived type calling the method and not passing a `Button` type in the `sender` slot.

A more typesafe approach to this is to use a lambda expression to pass the relevant button down in a type safe fashion.

```
btn_oldFile.Click += delegate { OldFileBrowse_Click(btn_oldFile); };
btn_newFile.Click += delegate { OldFileBrowse_Click(btn_newFile); };

protected void OldFileBrowse_Click(Button sender) {
  //if btn_oldFile called 
    // print to tbx_OldFile 
  //else 
    //print to tbx_NewFile 
}
```

Comment: Unnecessarily convoluted. Don't try to second-guess code that doesn't follow the established conventions, and don't ever write code that breaks them.

Comment: @Bradley, I don't consider the use of lambdas to create type safe code in any way convoluted.

Comment: The real solution is not to mark an event handler method as `protected` - horribly bad practice, since derived types aren't trying to trigger the event, they just want to execute the code that runs in response to it (presumably a more meaningful method). Derived types shouldn't even be aware of the controls on the base class... Also, what you posted aren't lambda expressions, just anonymous methods.